# SendEmail on Custom Activity

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

I have a little problem with a custom activity on my very complex workflow.
I follow this link to create what i need: [Creating Multiple Tasks from a SharePoint 2010 Workflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh128696.aspx)

Now I try to add a SendEmail activity after the CreateTask, check the image:
[image]

But this does not send the email, It finish the workflow and I dont get any error, and the only rare that I see in the log is this line (IDK if it's usefull)

```
Site Enumeration Stack:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSiteCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.HiddenListFullSyncJobDefinition.Execute(SPContentDatabase contentDatabase, SPJobState jobState)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPContentDatabaseJobDefinition.Execute(SPJobState jobState)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTimerJobInvokeInternal.Invoke(SPJobDefinition jd, Guid targetInstanceId, Boolean isTimerService, Int32& result)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTimerJobInvoke.Invoke(TimerJobExecuteData& data, Int32& result)
```

I would appreciate your help

Comment: can you check any errors on the eventlog and what does the ULS Log say? Is there only this message associated with it? Maybe you have a misconfigured smpt setting in your sharepoint env?

Comment: The smtp server is working, my workflow has several email notification, but only this don't work.
And the ULS doesn't say nothing only what I share in the post and I'm not sure if that message is from the activity.

greetings